# Merge code into a different branch at the end of BuildBot steps

Tags: buildbot

I have a buildbot setup which is able to checkout code from branch "a" and able to run a bunch of build, test commands on that code. While this works, now I want the code to be merged into branch "b" when all of the steps are successfully finished.

Is there a way in buildbot to do that?

Answer (score 0):

On all CI systems, there is always the option to drop down to the command line - in buildbot, you can use the [ShellCommand](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#step-ShellCommand) for that, e.g.:

```
f = BuildFactory()
f.addStep(ShellCommand(
              command=['make', 'test'], haltOnFailure=True))
f.addStep(ShellCommand(
              command=['git', 'merge', ...])
```

[`haltOnFailure`](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#common-parameters) ensures that the merge is only run when the tests have passed.

P.S.: of course, it's enough to use the `ShellCommand` for the merge step, the prior step(s) can be anything, as the `haltOnFailure` is a common option to all steps.